# HIPAA compliant project management for research groups

Tags: framework, document-management, collaboration, research, enterprise-portal

We are a 501c3 developing strategies for implementing social genomic medicine in clinics in several countries. 
We have several work groups each developing their own projects for their clinics which involve collection, analysis, evidence generation, and sustainability in the workflows.

We are having difficulty finding a software solution that can be used by the teams in their own work and administrated by the organization.

We need a low cost solution (under 50$ per month and not per user just groupwise) that can work with medical professionals who are not as computer savvy as the administrative staff.

We have looked into web portal services but have not yet found any options which support document and dataset collaboration features as well as privacy requirement satisfaction (HIPAA).

Can anyone in the medical research area provide any suggestions?

Due to the nature of the data collected and research being performed we are not able to be anonymize the data and retain its use ability. Datasets are shared between all groups.

Administration is a separate super-group which may access, monitor, support, and administer all other groups; we don't require any HIPAA compliance for this part but I'd like it there in case extension is required later which sounds possible.

Web based solutions would probably be the best option since the teams are spread out over several countries. They are running Windows 10 systems.